# How to convert a project to module

Tags: android, flutter

I created a new flutter project

And it's done a lot of things

Now I need to embed the flutter project into the native Android project

I only found some examples of importing flutter module

I tried to turn my project into a module, but it was a mess

Is there any quick way?

Comment: were you able to run non-native? on what platform? last time i heard flutter is already doing what you were trying to do. flutter uses Platform channel to communicate with dart code vice versa, you may want to look into that

Comment: @iamyadunandan android,My current project can be run independently，I'm not talking about channel, but hybrid development